# Error reading private key file using openssl lib

Tags: delphi, openssl

I'm trying to read a private key in order to use later in signing some data. I'm stuck at reading this private key file (Bad Key File). I did read another private key file (Good Key File) with no errors. I am new to OpenSSL.

## good Key File

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,EB51377407AB034BA6C4554097E3454C
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

## Bad Key File

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGNAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKBHYwdAIBAQQgvuua2biCekB5C2oW/Ip3
Hi7YVb9nyaQp7GKpb8OomWOgBwYFK4EEAAqhRANCAATGVHYUkO49tiWNbhQHbmtC
l1mW9L0btglwvhld9zFwQTNHq3g07RM4s4+DTmiQWBPtrF6S8xJekFiSs9dN6zl9
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

## My Code

```
var
  bp: PBIO;
  PrivKeyFile, FCertPassword : AnsiString;
begin
  Result := False;
  PrivKeyFile := 'private.pem'; 
  FCertPassword := '123456789';
  bp := BIO_new_file(PAnsiChar(PrivKeyFile), 'r');
  if CheckError() then Exit;
  try
      FPrivateKeyData := PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bp, nil, nil, PAnsiChar(FCertPassword));
      if CheckError() then Exit;
 finally
      BIO_free(bp);
  end;
end;
```

## Error message

error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Comment: What does `CheckError` do? Are you actually examining the result of whatever it is doing?

Comment: The PEM type `EC PRIVATE KEY` is supposed to be used for SEC1 format (republished in rfc5915) but your data is in fact in PKCS8 format which should have PEM type `PRIVATE KEY` (see rfc7468 sec 11). Delete the EC from the header and trailer, and tell whoever created this file they're incompetent. Also note this file is not encrypted (PKSC8 encrypted files have a _different_ type `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`) which may mean your supposedly private key has been exposed but that's not really ontopic here.

Comment: I did as @dave_thompson_085 advised, (Delete the EC from the header and trailer) and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [dave-thompson-085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) advised me, (Delete the EC from the header and trailer) and it is working now.