# Is there a chance to deal with unknown format of private key & certificate?

Tags: delphi, openssl

I'm working on a Delphi project where I will sign an invoice. I tested some OpenSSL Delphi ports and I had success in signing and verifying data. The problem is that I can't read either the key or the certificate files. I think there is a problem with key and certificate formats.

## Private key (private-key.pem)

```
MHQCAQEEIP0tXvA0mhzTBgjZaAGt+V3tWIr79nG/gs56jKFJb6gboAcGBSuBBAAKoUQDQgAE+39UxFUCaF5p51RTvwXL+YODEpITlTdI27S72pSPJEAjQs2jBb1sLS/xg8/y5555+d19KoLmLo6gMrxvINXaHw==
```

## Certificate (cert.pem)

```
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
```

## Code to read private key

```
    bp := BIO_new_file(PAnsiChar(PrivKeyFile), 'r');
    if CheckError() then Exit;
    try
      FPrivateKeyData := PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bp, nil, nil, PAnsiChar(FCertPassword));
      if CheckError() then Exit;
    finally
      BIO_free(bp);
    end;
```

## Code to read certificate

```
  bp := BIO_new_file(PAnsiChar(certFile), 'r');
  if CheckError then Exit;
  try
   _x509 := PEM_read_bio_X509(bp, nil, nil, PAnsiChar(FCertPassword));
   if CheckError then Exit;
  finally
    BIO_free(bp);
  end;
```

## Error Message in both cases

error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

If files format is not accepted by OpenSSL, is there any way to convert files format so I can use them with OpenSSL library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PEM IS NOT JUST BASE64.** Your files names say `.pem` and you try to read them with routines that handle PEM, but they *aren't* PEM. PEM is base64 (of certain data types) *with linebreaks and with header/trailer lines* -- these are not optional; see [rfc7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2).
[Your previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213718/error-reading-private-key-file-using-openssl-lib) had these correct and only the 'type' *in* the header/trailer wrong.

**Add header/trailer lines and linebreaks** as follows (edit: corrected privatekey type) and your files will work with your code:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIP0tXvA0mhzTBgjZaAGt+V3tWIr79nG/gs56jKFJb6gboAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAE+39UxFUCaF5p51RTvwXL+YODEpITlTdI27S72pSPJEAjQs2jBb1sLS/x
g8/y5555+d19KoLmLo6gMrxvINXaHw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Alternatively, you can decode the base64 to binary and then use the routines that parse binary rather than PEM, for this case `d2i_ECPrivateKey` and `d2i_x509`.

Note this privatekey is not encrypted, so you don't actually need the password (it is ignored).

Meta: I'm not sure this is really programming or development, but I needed formatting so I answered. If Q is closed, I will delete if requested.

Comment: I tried to add header and trailer and split data before I post this question but no luck. I did tried the following command from terminal :
openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in /media/ehab/Store/x/Certificates/private-key.pem
It gives me an error "unable to load Private Key
139900939658560:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag" and this error is similar to "error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag" which I get from Delphi program so I posted this question.

Comment: Certificate file accepted from Delphi program and for OpenSSL command
openssl x509 -noout -in /media/ehab/Store/x/Certificates/cert1.pem -subject

Comment: @Ehab: OOPS! I didn't look closely enough; that privatekey _is_ SEC1 format (unlike your previous Q which claimed SEC1 but was really PKCS8) so _this time_ the PEM label needs to be `EC PRIVATE KEY`. Fixed. You still won't be able to read it with `openssl rsa`, because it isn't an RSA key; you can display it with `openssl ec -in fixedfile -text [-noout]` or `openssl pkey -in fixedfile -text [-noout]`.